# Cannot run Gradle Project with Spring-Boot dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Using Gradle version 6.5.1 and Java version 11

Here is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.1.RELEASE')
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE')
    }
}

configurations {
    runtimeLibs
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.shutl.Application"
}
```

Here is the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have tried changing Gradle versions to 7 but that hasn't changed anything. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I would try maybe using a different java sdk

Comment: Try running the build with `--debug` and `--stacktrace`.

Comment: https://textdoc.co/bVAzDScaYuBW56RE

Comment: Changed to OpenJDK 13 and still the same error